# How to combine these two sentences?

Tags: sentence

Cannot feed A of shape a1 for B of shape b1, which is b2.
A is a2.

I want to express something like this:
[A,of shape a1, is a2] ----feed---> [B, of shape b1, is b2]

Does 'which' always modify the nearest one?
And then how to modify the far one?

Comment: What is the sentence even supposed to mean? To me, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Error information was given by the program. It doesn't mean a lot. I thought 'which ...` modified the value. I want to know the usage.

Comment: Ohhh... I understand. Though - "*Cannot feed the **value** of shape (1,1) for **the** tensor of shape (3,3), which is... **ten**.*" - makes much more sense.

Comment: [A,of shape a1, is a2] --feed---> [B, of shape b1, is b2]

Comment: Actually, I want to express the information like this. Is this way more easy to understand?

Comment: Edit your comments into your question.